# Convert comparision function into range

Tags: plotting, functions, regions

I have function:

```
f[x_]:=0<=x<=Pi
```

How do I convert this into range `{x,0,Pi}` to use for example with plotting:

```
Plot[g[x],{x,0,Pi}]
```

Comment: `f[x_]:=0<=x<=Pi; g[x_]:=Sin[x]; Plot[g[x],f[x]//.lo_<=var_<=hi_->{var,lo,hi}]`

Comment: Assuming that `g[x_] := Sin[x]`,  `Plot[g[x], {x, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, f[x]]]` since you are essentially trying to define a `RegionFunction`.

Comment: `Join[{x}, Cases[f[x], _?NumericQ, All]]` or `Prepend[Cases[f[x], _?NumericQ, All], x]` or `{x, ##} & @@ Cases[f[x], _?NumericQ, All]` or `Insert[Cases[f[x], _?NumericQ, All], x, 1]`

Comment: In Mathematica there are ALWAYS at least 6 different ways of doing ANYTHING, at least one of which is completely incomprehensible when you first see it, and sometimes for far longer than that. ;} Bill

Comment: Yeah, @Bill, in at least ten ways! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 0 <= x <= Pi
g = Sin;


Plot[g[x], x ∈ ImplicitRegion[f[x], x]]
```

[image]

For the specific `f` in OP, you can also use

```
Plot[g[x], {#2, #, #3} & @@ f[x]]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Plot[g[x], Reverse@(RotateRight@(List @@ f[x]))]
```

As a function:

```
☺ = Reverse@(RotateRight@(List @@ #)) &;

Plot[g[x], ☺@f[x]]
```

As pointed out @Syed, another way:

```
Plot[g[x], (List @@ f[x])[[{2, 1, 3}]]]

(*Thanks, Syed!*)
```

Comment: `Plot[g[x], (List @@ f[x])[[{2, 1, 3}]]]` for this case only though.